# DevExpress WinForms XtraRichEdit - Export Document to an Image

Tags: devexpress, export, rich-text-editor, dxperience

I'm looking for an ability to export documents (e.g. doc, rtf, txt) as images. Does [XtraRichEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4946) support such functionality? This is definitely supported by Aspose.Words, but I'm not sure about DevExpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the [XtraPrinting](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2079) Library. Please refer to the code below:

```
using DevExpress.XtraPrinting;
//...
PrintableComponentLink link = new PrintableComponentLink(printingSystem1);
link.Component = richEditControl1;
link.CreateDocument();
link.ExportToImage(@"c:\image.png", new ImageExportOptions()
{
    Format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png,
    ExportMode = ImageExportMode.DifferentFiles,
    Resolution = 96
});
```

Comment: Can this solution produce multipage output?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have updated my answer. Please, also take a look at [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingImageExportOptionsMembersTopicAll)